Django- How to use django-silk to work in running tests
I use the django-silk to profile the APIs of my Django project (Django + DRF). Currently, I call APIs in the browser (using DRF browsable API) and then I can see the API profiling data in the silk. When I run the test command, it doesn't capture requests and responses and therefore it doesn't create any profiling data to show.
Is there a way to force the silk to work in the test environment? My idea is instead of calling APIs one by one in the browser and then checking the silk, only run the tests and then see the profiling data after the tests are finished.
Update 
The reason behind this is, the Django uses Transactions in running tests. So after each test function, it rolls back the transaction and data will be deleted from the database.

throwing a guess, it could be because of Mock-DB getting destroyed after running tests. try to run tests without destroying db (something like --keepdb flag)

The issue is related to Transactions in Django tests. Django wraps each test function inside a database Transaction and at the end of test, transaction will be rolled back, so all the data that have been created during the test, will be removed (include the silk data)
